# It's taking forever to sychronize wallet

Tags: transactions

I was sending bitcoins from Mt. Gox to my bit wallet.  However, the wallet still says its sychronizing.  It says there are 18600 blocks remaining and the count is reducing extremely slowly.  It's been synching for almost a day now.  Are the bit coins I sent from Mt. Gox lost?  Any help would be awesome.

Comment: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/FAQ#How_long_does_.22synchronizing.22_take_when_the_Bitcoin_client_is_first_installed.3F_What.27s_it_doing.3F

Comment: I would like to spend my coins and it still looks like another day of synching.  I was reading up on how to utilize a different wallet.  What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: Did you read what I linked? `If you feel that this process takes too long, you can download a pre-synchronized blockchain from http://eu2.bitcoincharts.com/blockchain/. Alternatively, you can try an alternative "lite" client such as Multibit or a super-light client like electrum, though these clients have somewhat weaker security, are less mature, and don't contribute to the health of the P2P network.`